# Marshalling call to main thread from System.Timers.Timer

Tags: multithreading, timer, marshalling

I have a tough question (for me at least).  I'm working on a Windows Service written in VB.net.  I'm using a System.Timers.Timer class to periodically call a delegate method to see if there is any work to do.  The timing of the processing is not critical and I have attempted to prevent re-entry into the worker method by disabling the Timer as soon as the method is invoked and starting it again at the end.

However, the Timer class Elapsed events occur on a different thread.  Searching online, most people are using Windows forms which implement the ISynchronize interface to marshal the call back to the originating thread.  Ideally I don't want to use Windows Forms to achieve this.  Is there an easy way to re-direct the call back to the original thread?

Alternatively is there a framework class I can inherit to do this?  Or at worst a simple implementation of ISynchronize?

```
Imports System.Timers
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data


Public Class Application
    Implements IDisposable


Private WithEvents _Timer As Timer



Private Sub SleepTimerCallback(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles _Timer.Elapsed

    ' TODO need to find a way to bring this method back on the main thread.

    ' Temporarily disable the timer elapsed event so that we don't have event re-entrance.
    If Me._Timer.Enabled = True Then Me._Timer.Enabled = False

    ' Do Work.

    ' Re-enable the timer elapsed event.
    _Timer.Enabled = True

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If that's all your service does, then you probably shouldn't be using a service, but instead a simple console application that you execute via a scheduled task.

Answer (score 2):

Your timer enabling / disabling code has a subtle bug. You have:

```
If Me._Timer.Enabled = True Then Me._Timer.Enabled = False

' Do work

' Re-enable the timer
_Timer.Enabled = True
```

So if the timer is disabled on entry, your code still executes. Granted, you shouldn't get multiple calls, but your conditional check there is essentially useless.

A better way to do it is to initialize your timer with `AutoReset` set to `False`. That makes the timer tick only once. Then, at the end of your event handler, call `Start` again to restart the timer. That way you can't possibly get multiple concurrent calls to the handler.

`System.Timers.Timer` has the unfortunate property of squashing exceptions, as pointed out in the documentation:

> the Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event.

So if your event handler throws an exception you will never know it. Except that the timer won't be re-enabled. So you need to write:

```
Private Sub SleepTimerCallback(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles _Timer.Elapsed
    Try
        ' TODO need to find a way to bring this method back on the main thread.
    Finally    
        ' Re-enable the timer elapsed event.
        _Timer.Start()
    End
End Sub
```

And you'll probably want to handle exceptions in there, too. Otherwise you'll never know that they occur.

Comment: Hi Jim.  Thanks for the advice on using AutoReset and Exception handling.  Very useful.  The bug you pointed out is because I actually run the method once without the timer triggering it at which point the timer is not running.  Every subsequent entry has the timer enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Marshaling a call from a worker thread to a **specific** other thread is non-trivial.  Only certain kind of threads can support this.  The main thread in a Winforms or WPF app qualify, they are special because they have a dispatcher loop.  The universal solution to the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

There's a very good reason they need to do this, a user interface is pretty fundamentally thread-unsafe.  You can only update the UI from the thread that created it.  So it is quite important that you can always get code to run on that specific thread.

This infrastructure is entirely missing from a service.  It doesn't even have a notion of a "main thread".  It doesn't need it, there is no UI.  You should therefore not have a need to marshal the call, just let your Elapsed event handler do the job.

Do note that you have to take care of some details to make an Elapsed event handler safe.  You should set the timer's AutoReset property to False to ensure the event handler won't be called again while it is still busy.  That rarely comes to a good end.  You already did this yourself but using AutoReset is better.  And you should always use Try/Catch to catch exceptions.  That Timer class has the nasty habit of swallowing exceptions without a diagnostic, your service will stop running and you'll have no idea why.  Log the exception in the Catch clause so you'll know why it stopped.

Comment: Thanks Hans, very useful comments.  I wasn't trying to write a multithreaded application in the first place and only found out through debugging that the Timer.Elapsed event occurs on a different thread!  Its helpful to know that it should be safe to run on separate threads as long as I don't get re-entry.